# jfrog artifactory set up a smart remote repository for generic type

Tags: artifactory

I am using Artifactory pro and want to set up an smart remote repository of type generic. The documentations says the path should be /api/<*type*>/<*id*> but does not say anything about the *type* string for generic repos. Are smart remote repositories not supported for the generic type?

Answer (score 1):

Generic Smart Repos **are** supported in Artifactory. You simply do not need to add the /api string to use it.

The reason to add it in other repo types (like npm for example) is to go through the relevant artifactory package api when preforming actions via the package client.

For example, in npm, if you do not add the /api and you run an

```
npm install
```

than Artifactory will not know it needs to preform some "api actions", like modifying the package json to download dependencies from the Artifactory repo.

With a generic repo type, there's simply no special API or action related to a specific package type that need to happen, so you can add the repo URL "as is", for example

```
http://my-remote-artifactory:port/artifactory/generic-local
```

Comment: Thanks a log for confirmation.